# AngularJs and ExpressJs. How are they talking with each other?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, express

I'm currently trying to figure out how to associate back end nodejs with front end angularjs.

In my angular controller:

```
$http.get('/api/getPlayer/' + id)
    .success(function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    })
    .error(function(data) {
        console.log('error: '+data);
    });
```

Say I want to create an api that gets information on a player called getPlayer with their id.

In my routes.js:

```
module.exports = function(app) {
    app.get('/api/getPlayer/:id', function(req, res) {
        console.log('hi');
        var test = {
            a: test
        };
        res.json(test)
    });
}
```

My understanding is that the http.get in angular will call app.get. Am I getting the wrong idea? I'm still fairly new to routing and web applications in general.

Comment: It will call the http endpoint you've created. It won't "call app.get", but maybe you didn't mean that like it sounded.

Comment: @DaveNewton so my routes.js code isnt actually creating an http endpoint called '/api/getPlayer/id"?

Comment: It is. Your language was imprecise, the client side doesn't call "app.get", it hits the endpoint, just like I said.